# Why is my css transformation not working?

Tags: html, css

I want my logos to have a cool "shadow" appear to them when I hover on them, but it isn't working. I added some type of border so that when I hover on it, it appears but only on the edges, I used z-index: -1;, so that my logos appear instead of the border and then with a transformation when I hover on the logos, the border would come to the side but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<footer>
    <ul class = "bottom">
        <li><a href = "https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href = "#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer{
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   padding: 50px 0;
   background-color: #262626;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align: center;
}

.bottom{
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
}

.bottom li{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   font-size: 30px;
   height: 60px;
   width: 60px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: black;
   line-height: 60px;
   margin: 0 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.bottom li a{
   color: #666;
}

.bottom li:before{
   position: absolute;
   content: '';
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #d35400;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   border-radius: 50%;
   z-index: -1;
   transition: .5s;
   transform: scale(0.9);
}

.bottom li a:hover:before{
   transform: scale(1.2);
   box-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you want your end result to be, is this close?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #262626;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.bottom li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottom li a {
  color: #666;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bottom li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400;
  border: 2px solid #d35400;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <ul class="bottom">
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class = "fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your styling is on `.bottom li::before {` thus `.bottom li` is what you want to trigger on hover.

```
.bottom li:hover{
 transform: scale(1.2);
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px #d35400;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/42w7hgo6/3/

Do note that you have two `display` in .footer and `before` for CSS3 has two colons: `::before`

Comment: This is close but not what I want. The color that I get inside the border, I want that outside instead of just the box-shadow. And then on the inside I'll try to get the logo (f, youtube, twitter) to lighten up on hover aswell.

Comment: I've updated the link. Not sure I understand, so I removed the orange color inside the box. Then you want to lighten up the logo? I've added a white color to the logo.

Answer (score -1):

This uses box-shadow with hover. So the box will highlight when you hover on the box.

`CSS`

```
.bottom {
  transition: box-shadow .3s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.bottom:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2); 
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/ovdojoey/pen/BomKyZ

Comment: when posting code, please use a snippet whenever possible. this is much cleaner to look at, and you can even run the code in this website instead of copying into whatever program you use and run it there.

Comment: Alright, noted. This is my first time answering in StackOverflow